# Display the whole image

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, layout

There is a code. I layout class `content`. You need to display a picture `<img src="../img/mobileimage.png"></img>`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  all__buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.header__button');
  /*selected__button.click= function(){
        selected__button.backgroundColor='#5f3ec0';
    
  };*/
  /*
    function changeColor(inputbutton) {
        inputbutton.style.backgroundColor='#5f3ec0';
    
    }
    
  */

  [].forEach.call(all__buttons, function(selected__button) {
    selected__button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.target.style.backgroundColor = '#5f3ec0';
      event.target.style.color = '#ffffff';

    });
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.globalcontainer {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 4%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 4%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header>.header__text {
  position: relative;
  width: 93px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 129px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: TT Norms;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 100%;
  /* identical to box height, or 24px */
  color: #000000;
}


/*
.header__buttons {
    left: 0;
    top: 193px;
}
*/

.header__button {
  width: 75px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 1.75%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.header__buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 7px 15px 7px 0px;
  /*margin-right: 10%;*/
}

.mobileimage {}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.css">-->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/mobile.css" media="screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 639px)"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/tablet.css" media="screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 1023px)"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/desktop.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1920px)"></link>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="globalcontainer">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="header__text">
        Обзоры
      </div>
      <div class="header__buttons">
        <!-- <span> -->
        <button class="header__button">Все</button>
        <button class="header__button">Видео</button>
        <button class="header__button">Текст</button>
        <button class="header__button">Обзоры</button>
        <button class="header__button">Сравнения</button>
        <button class="header__button">Краш видео</button>
        <button class="header__button">Распаковка</button>
        <!-- </span> -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="cardexample">
        <div class="mobileimage">
          <img src="../img/mobileimage.png"></img>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cardexample">
      </div>
      <div class="cardexample">
      </div>
      <div class="cardexample">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jsactions.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The page is displayed like this

[real view][image: 1]

but it is necessary (It is necessary that the picture is displayed in full)

[neededview][image: 2]

[Image from site][image: 3]

It is necessary to display the entire drawing, not part of it. Quick help is required. The drawing used to scale normally earlier.

Comment: `img { max-width: 100% }`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  all__buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.header__button');
  /*selected__button.click= function(){
        selected__button.backgroundColor='#5f3ec0';
    
  };*/
  /*
    function changeColor(inputbutton) {
        inputbutton.style.backgroundColor='#5f3ec0';
    
    }
    
  */

  [].forEach.call(all__buttons, function(selected__button) {
    selected__button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.target.style.backgroundColor = '#5f3ec0';
      event.target.style.color = '#ffffff';

    });
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.globalcontainer {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 4%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 4%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header>.header__text {
  position: relative;
  width: 93px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 129px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: TT Norms;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 100%;
  /* identical to box height, or 24px */
  color: #000000;
}


/*
.header__buttons {
    left: 0;
    top: 193px;
}
*/

.header__button {

  width:100%;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
background-size:cover;
}

.header__buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 7px 15px 7px 0px;
  /*margin-right: 10%;*/
}

img{
max-width:100%;
}

#back{
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.css">-->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/mobile.css" media="screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 639px)"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/tablet.css" media="screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 1023px)"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/desktop.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1920px)"></link>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="globalcontainer">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="header__text">
        Обзоры
      </div>
      <div class="header__buttons" id="back">
        <!-- <span> -->
        <button class="header__button">Все</button>
        <button class="header__button">Видео</button>
        <button class="header__button">Текст</button>
        <button class="header__button">Обзоры</button>
        <button class="header__button">Сравнения</button>
        <button class="header__button">Краш видео</button>
        <button class="header__button">Распаковка</button>
        <!-- </span> -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="cardexample">
        <div class="mobileimage" id="back">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503023345310-bd7c1de61c7d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTJ8fG1hbnxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80"></img>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cardexample">
      </div>
      <div class="cardexample">
      </div>
      <div class="cardexample">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jsactions.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```